# iterate through arraylist and display elements respectively using a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to iterate through this array.

```
const array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];
```

and display the first item by default in a div and use a button to display the next item (also replace the old item) in the same div i did try this but it didn't work

```
const quizConainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
const next = document.getElementById('next');

    const array = [
      '<h1>item1</h1>',
      '<h1>item2</h1>',
      '<h1>item3</h1>',
      '<h1>item4</h1>',
      '<h1>item5</h1>',
    ];

    quizConainer.innerHTML = array[0];

    function nextItem() {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (quizConainer.innerHTML === array[i]) {
          quizConainer.innerHTML = array[i++];
        }
      }
    }

    next.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
```

and thats the html

```
 <div id=""></div>
 <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this one

In this example, I added a global variable to hold the current position of the array that's being used. And the check is done with that particular variable only. 
Also, it is not a good practice to hold HTML tags in an array. So I changed it as well.

This example will start from the zeroth position and will iterate till the end of the array and then will again start from the beginning.

```js
const quizConainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
const next = document.getElementById('next');
let currPosition = 0; //To hold the element which is currently in DOM

const array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'];

quizConainer.innerHTML = '<h1>' + array[0] + '</h1>';

function nextItem() {
  if(currPosition === array.length - 1)
    currPosition = 0;
  else 
    currPosition++;
    
  quizConainer.innerHTML = '<h1>' + array[currPosition] + '</h1>'
}

next.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
```

```html
 <div id="quiz"></div>
 <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `counter` and keep a track of the current element in display.Also as the first element is default shown there may not be any need to put it in the array.

```js
const quizConainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
const next = document.getElementById('next');
const array = [
  '<h1>item2</h1>',
  '<h1>item3</h1>',
  '<h1>item4</h1>',
  '<h1>item5</h1>',
];
let counter = 0

function nextItem() {
  if (counter < array.length) {
    quizConainer.innerHTML = array[counter];
    counter++;
  }

}

next.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
  <h1>item1</h1>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable . That can help you here instead of loop .
Edit : Added [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py2twf8c/)

```
<div id="quiz"></div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<script>
    const quizConainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
const next = document.getElementById('next');
    let i = 1;
    const array = [
    '<h1>item1</h1>',
    '<h1>item2</h1>',
    '<h1>item3</h1>',
    '<h1>item4</h1>',
    '<h1>item5</h1>',
    ];

    quizConainer.innerHTML = array[0];

    function nextItem() {
        i = i % array.length;   //If you want it reset and start from first on traversing the entire array
        console.log(i);
        quizConainer.innerHTML = array[i];
        i = i +1;
    }

    next.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
</script>
```